# How to reset unity in Ubuntu 15.10 without WiFi

Tags: login, login-screen

I have just recovered my Laptop from a GRUB issue now when I want to login, the screen splashes and go back to login screen, I can login fine using terminal, 
Some people say you need to reset unity but the problem is my WiFi don't work idk the reason. I tried to reset unity via 
Dconf reset -f /org/compiz command but it says: cannot autolunch d-bus without x11 $display

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried restart the lightdm service.
or u can do : apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-session
as per this url:
http://sourcedigit.com/16407-how-to-fix-failed-to-start-session-at-ubuntu-login/

and if problem still exists than try to login as a guest account, if succeeded than go back to **ctrl+alt+f1** check the permission & ownership of your user:
ls -la /home/user
check optput of these files:
drwx------  3 user user  4096 Aug  6  2015 .gnome
-rw-------  1 user user    49 Jan  1  2010 .Xauthority
if permission are not like this than set the permission and also do chown to user for all files in the user & reboot system, hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: the apt-get command requires network connectivity? guest session don't work as well

Comment: so now go with second solution which i have mentioned, problem can caused because of permissions also,  rm the existing .Xauthority file and  give the full permission chmod -R 777 /home/user and make user the owner of all files with chown -R user:user /home/user  and reboot.  (reboot will create again new .Xauthority file)

Comment: still the same, nothing changed